# Arrays with Stringand integer

Tags: vb.net

I want to print the array - filetable 1. I have used a class to define 'Data'

can somebody help with the syntax to print this array in a text file Tx

```
   Dim filetable1 As New List(Of Data)
    For x = 0 To (lineCount1 - 2)
        '''''c = 1
        Array.Sort(file1items)
        If file1items(x) = file1items(x + 1) Then
            c = c + 1
        Else
            c = 1
            filetable1.Add(New Data(file1items(x), c))
        End If

    Next

Public Class Data
    Public PN As String
    Public Count As Integer


    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            ' Gets the property value.
            Return PN
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            ' Sets the property value.
            PN = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ct() As Integer
        Get
            ' Gets the property value.
            Return Count
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            ' Sets the property value.
            Count = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub Capitalize()
        ' Capitalize the value of the property.
        PN = UCase(PN)
        Count = UCase(Count)
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(PName As String, ct1 As Integer)
        Name = PName
        ct = ct1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If it's going to a text file then it's not printing, it's saving to a file. Have you searched how to write to a text file in general?  If so then why aren't we seeing the code for that?   You do and then, if it doesn't work, you post here and show what you did and we then help you fix it.  If you haven't done anything then there's nothing to fix.

Comment: Right now, I want to print. I meant eventually I will write into a text file. I could not figure out the syntax to print it

Comment: If writing to a text file is something you want to do later then why even mention it?  It's irrelevant and serves only to confuse the matter.  If you want to print, do some research on printing, make an attempt and then, if you run into an issue, post back here about that specific issue.  If you haven't actually tried anything yet then posting a question here is premature.

Comment: Clue - Google vb.net system.drawing.printing